# importing multiple csv files into existing worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to import multiple CSV files from a folder into an existing workbook. I this workbook I need the CSV files to import to and overwrite existing sheets named the same as the CSV file name. I need to overwrite the sheets as I have formulas that refer to them. I have the following but it creates new sheets in a new workbook. I am new to excel and would appreciate any help you can offer. I am using Excel 2019. Thanks.

```
Sub CombineTextFiles()
    Dim FilesToOpen
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim wkbAll As Workbook
    Dim wkbTemp As Workbook
    Dim sDelimiter As String

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    sDelimiter = "|"

    FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
      (FileFilter:="Text Files (*.csv), *.csv", _
      MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Text Files to Open")

    If TypeName(FilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
        MsgBox "No Files were selected"
        GoTo ExitHandler
    End If

    x = 1
    Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
    wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Copy
    Set wkbAll = ActiveWorkbook
    wkbTemp.Close (False)
    wkbAll.Worksheets(x).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
      Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
      ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
      Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
      Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
      Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
    x = x + 1

    While x <= UBound(FilesToOpen)
        Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
        With wkbAll
            wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Move After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            .Worksheets(x).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
              Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
              TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
              ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
              Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
              Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
              Other:=True, OtherChar:=sDelimiter
        End With
        x = x + 1
    Wend

ExitHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set wkbAll = Nothing
    Set wkbTemp = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me. I prefer [Excel.QueryTables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.QueryTables)

```
Sub CombineTextFiles()
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim xlsheet As Worksheet
    Dim qt As QueryTable
    Dim txtfilesToOpen As Variant, txtfile As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    txtfilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
                 (FileFilter:="Text Files (*.csv), *.csv", _
                  MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Text Files to Open")

    For Each txtfile In txtfilesToOpen
        ' FINDS EXISTING WORKSHEET
        For Each xlsheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If xlsheet.Name = Replace(fso.GetFileName(txtfile), ".csv", "") Then
                xlsheet.Activate
                GoTo ImportCSV
            End If
        Next xlsheet

        ' CREATES NEW WORKSHEET IF NOT FOUND
        Set xlsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add( _
                             After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
        xlsheet.Name = Replace(fso.GetFileName(txtfile), ".csv", "")
        xlsheet.Activate
        GoTo ImportCSV

ImportCSV:
        ' DELETE EXISTING DATA
        ActiveSheet.Range("A:Z").EntireColumn.Delete xlShiftToLeft

        ' IMPORT DATA FROM TEXT FILE
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & txtfile, _
          Destination:=ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1))
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"

            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With

        For Each qt In ActiveSheet.QueryTables
            qt.Delete
        Next qt
    Next txtfile

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Successfully imported text files!", vbInformation, "SUCCESSFUL IMPORT"

    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: @JakeHoward Glad that it worked for you. Please accept my answer.To mark an answer as accepted, please click on the check mark beside the answer below down pointing triangle  to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me with one small change. The code deleted the cells which broke some of my formulas that were linked. I added this line to clear the entire sheet instead. I appreciate your help. 
    
    Sheets("Sheet4").Cells.ClearContents

Comment: This works well but the existing worksheets must contain the .csv extension or a new sheet is created with the .csv extension. How would I change this code to reference only the file name without the extension?

Comment: @JakeHoward During my sample test I did not come across this problem. Files checked sheets without csv extension and created additional sheets without csv extension . Let me explore once again. Please give me some time.

Comment: @JakeHoward Please see the snapshot uploaded at imgur <https://imgur.com/sSzmLhF>. Sample directory on right side has other than `.csv` files but the File Dialog on the Left side does not allow other than `.csv` files to be selected. So the problem stated by you should not give trouble..It works fine at my end. I stand corrected in my previous comments Files with .csv extensions only were selected and created sheets without csv extension. Sorry so many things at my end that this line erred.

Comment: I finally resolved the issue. It was a very simple mistake. My source file extensions were capitalized .CSV and my code had lower case .csv. I changed the code to capitalized file extensions and now the code works flawlessly. Thank you very much for taking the time to help a beginner like myself. I really appreciate it. Hopefully this will help someone else in the future as well.

Comment: Glad to note it. Appreciate your efforts to solve the problem.